# Is it possible to display related posts from same category as the current post?

Tags: wordpress

I found other post on this topic but it did not help me.
If I add this code to my code, is it possible to display related posts from same category as the current post?

I'm posting the code below to show what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<?php
$related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => 
wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 'numberposts' => 5, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );
if( $related ) 
    foreach( $related as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php }

    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: It would help us to define what you are trying to do, even post the link.

Comment: We couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve here. Please explain a bit more about the issue with some screenshot or link. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for replaying me...

when i view a single post ... i need some related post title on this related post show same categories

Comment: see this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/related-posts-via-categories/

i need it by custom code

Answer (score 0):

Display related posts from the same category

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );

        if ( empty( $terms ) ) $terms = array();

        $term_list = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );

        $related_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term_list
                )
            )
        );

        $my_query = new WP_Query($related_args);

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

        the_title();
        echo "<br>";

        endwhile;
        }
    wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: check my new answer