# Related posts - Query posts for each shared category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have already asked this on wordpress.stackexchange, but time is of the essence and I still haven't received a reply, so I'll try again here.

I have two top-level categories, named "**Projects**" and "**Services**".
"**Services**" has several sub-categories, like "**cleaning**, "**building**", "**plumbing**", etcetera.

- Posts that have the category "**Projects**" may have multiple sub-categories of "**Services**", but never "**Services**" itself.
- There are also posts that have one or several sub-categories of "**Services**", but not "**Projects**". These posts also never have "**Services**" itself.

In *single.php*, at the bottom of the page (after `the_content();`), I wanted to build a sort of "related projects" section, where I'd like to query only the posts that have the category "**Projects**", and that share *at least one* "**Services**" sub-category with the current post.

***Example:*** The current post has the categories "**Projects**", "**plumbing**" and "**cleaning**".
The "related projects" section would have links to all posts with "**Projects**"+"**plumbing**" and "**Projects**"+"**cleaning**". These posts may have other "**Services**" sub-categories.

If the post *doesn't* have "**Projects**" then it displays projects with a specific "**Services**" sub-category.

***Example:*** The current post has the "**building**" category. The "related projects" section would have links to all posts with "**Projects**"+"**building**". These posts may have other "**Services**" sub-categories.

I'm probably missing the point, I'm relatively amateurish when it comes to Wordpress and I don't know very many functions, and sometimes I don't realise how some functions interact. I'm struggling with the approach to this problem. What conditions should I use? In which order?

If I add all categories (`get_categoryies();`) to the array that I use as `$args` for my query, the query will display all posts with "**Projects**", even those that don't share the same "**Services**" sub-categories. If I exclude "**Projects**", it will display all posts, even those that are not projects.
I also tried listing all categories a post has with `wp_list_categories();`, but I don't really understand how that function works. I need some ideas on how to fine-filtering the results of the queries.

Comment: check answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792054/is-it-possible-to-display-related-posts-from-same-category-as-the-current-post/47792933?noredirect=1#comment82552580_47792933

Comment: Didn't know the `get_the_terms()` function and the `tax_query` argument, they look promising. Gonna mess around a bit with that.
Thanks!